# Sum of column in using mysqli and php

Tags: php, mysql, iis, mysqli

I am tring to get the sum of a column and the show it on my page using this code but it keeps returning a "1" when it should return "23" for example. I check my sql statement and it works fine. This is the code I am using. (note: My server is iis with php)

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$sql="SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM td";

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo $row['total'];}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

ok so I added the while thing and it just breaks my code I get a white page.

I now removed the ! in the mysqli_query and I still get a white page, not sure if its me or the server that is not playing nice.

This may be unrelated but when I removed the ! from the mysqli_query from my other code it broke it.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$date = $_POST['date'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO td (date, comment, amount) VALUES ('$date', '$comment', '$amount')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Everything is fixed Thanks Everyone!!!

Comment: you need to fetch the data and then get `total`.

Comment: how do I about fetching the data? I barley know what I am doing.

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo $row['total']; }`

Comment: Remove the `!` in `!mysqli_query` --- `!` means "negation".

Comment: Ok, you need to pass DB connection to it. Do `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);` and make sure your DB connection is `mysqli` and not `mysql`

Comment: You're going all over the place. First the `!` for `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));` is normal. The `!` is allowed saying if there NO connection, then DIE. This doesn't apply to your fetching data from your original question/code.

Comment: ok I see my problem Thanks everything is fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');

$sql="SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM td";

$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   echo $row['total'];
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As said in a comment above, you don't need the ! infront of the query method.

Comment: This worked great Thanks, but I may have broke another part of my code.

Comment: for new bee, you can add your connection variable here 
Try this:
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);